# SQL - Getting an integer relative to a date column

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date column called "Expiry_Date". What I've been asked to do is retrieve an integer based on the month relative to the current, for example:

Current Date: 7th May 2016

```
MyTable
----------
1) 12th May
2) 31st May
3) 2nd June
4) 11 June
5) 19 June
6) 28th July
7) 1st August
```

The result would be:

```
1) 1
2) 1
3) 2
4) 2
5) 2
6) 3
7) 4
```

So, it's getting the month number relative to the current for the given date (or periods). This also has to work across years so "1 January 2017" would be "9" etc.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `expiry_date`?

Comment: It's just listed as "DATE" in Sql Developer. I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: Sound like a homework assignment, if not someone needs to rewrite the schema to ensure that the column holds dates as a date or datetime type and not as a string. What have you tried so far.

Comment: Homework assignment - if only! The reason why I'm asking is because it's certainly been a while since I've last done any SQL (University 9 years ago). My guess would be to get the date and somehow subtract it from the current and somehow turn it into it a single integer value. Talking of which, after thinking about it I'm just looking at DATEDIFF and maybe specifying a month only parameter

Comment: @RobertMeyer - that is a good start. Get the current date, subtract from the date in the table, and get the total months portion. I think if you google Oracle date functions you will be able to put together a working answer without too much effort.

Comment: Thanks Igor. Yeah, I just needed a kick up the bum to get this myself. Should be fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the function MONTHS_BETWEEN solves.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm

Something like:

```
round(months_between(expiry_date, date '2016-05-07') + 1)
```